# remove 12:00 am time on gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How do I remove the time portion on gridview?I tried some answer in stack but its now working for me.

Here is my gridview

[image]

here is my code for date time and asp .net code as well.

```
    var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
        var date = dateAndTime.Date;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_now",date);
```

and html gridview mark up

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
                 CssClass="table table-hover table-striped"
                 OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField Text="Select" CommandName="Select" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                <ItemStyle></ItemStyle>
            </asp:ButtonField>
               <asp:BoundField DataField="payment_date" HeaderText="Date of Payment"
                SortExpression="DateField" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="transaction_id" HeaderText="Trans I.D"
                SortExpression="DateField" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="transaction_number" HeaderText="Transaction number"
                SortExpression="DateField" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="product_id" HeaderText="Product I.D"
                SortExpression="DateField" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="productName" HeaderText="Product"
                SortExpression="DateField" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I didn't post the entire sql query because it's quite long.
How do I remove the time portion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the format using `DataFormatString` attribute.

```
DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
```

So, it should be..

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="payment_date" HeaderText="Date of Payment"
            SortExpression="DateField" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"/>
```

Comment: Do you mean, gridview not showing anything after change ?

Comment: @rainalasa might help !

Comment: I  figured it out. I've just change my date variable to this `var date = dateAndTime.Date.ToShortDateString();` and added you code to my markup.

Comment: Glad your issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
var date = dateAndTime.Date;
```

should be

```
var date = dateAndTime.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

(arrange the dd and MM in the right order according to your locality)

Agreed, I find it a bit silly that dateAndTime.Date doesn't actually strip the time portion, it just zero's it instead

In a simpler way, this will also work

```
var date = dateAndTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```